# ValidatesOnExceptions is not working in Silverlight VS2010

Tags: silverlight, validation, data-binding

I'm using VS2010 and Silverlight 5.

I have a sinple Silverlight project that declares a class (Student) and a view with textboxes bound to the Student properties.

The Student class throws an exception if the age entered is < 100 or < 0, then in the textbox bound to Age, I mark: ValidatesOnException = True.

**I run the app with VS2010 and the exception is not intercepted by the "binding engine", it simply bubles up to the user.**

**But if I run it with VS2012, everything goes ok. If an error is entered the textbox gets highlighted in red and the error is shown**

I want to be able to use VS2010.

Could it be the fact that I have both VS2010 and VS2012 installed in the same machine. I have them installed since quite a while and didn't have any other problem.

This is my Student class:

```
public class Student {
    private string _name;
    public string Name {
        get { return _name; }
        set { _name = value; }
    }

    private int _age;
    public int Age {
        get { return _age; }
        set {
            if (value > 100 || value < 0) {
                throw new Exception("Please enter an age between 0 and 100");
            }
            _age = value;
        }
    }
}
```

This is the view:

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot"
      Background="White">
    <TextBlock Height="23"
               HorizontalAlignment="Left"
               Margin="66,48,0,0"
               Name="textBlock1"
               Text="Name"
               VerticalAlignment="Top" />
    <TextBox Name="txtName"
             Text="{Binding Name, Mode=TwoWay, ValidatesOnExceptions=True}"
             Height="23"
             HorizontalAlignment="Left"
             VerticalAlignment="Top"
             Width="185"
             Margin="121,44,0,0" />
    <TextBlock Height="23"
               HorizontalAlignment="Left"
               Margin="78,77,0,0"
               Name="textBlock2"
               Text="Age"
               VerticalAlignment="Top" />
    <TextBox Name="txtAge"
             Text="{Binding Age, Mode=TwoWay, ValidatesOnExceptions=True}"
             Height="23"
             HorizontalAlignment="Left"
             VerticalAlignment="Top"
             Width="120"
             Margin="121,73,0,0" />

</Grid>
```

What could it be?

Comment: When are you assigning the viewmodel to the view??? I have had problems with this when I assigned the viewmodel to the view once the view was already created.

Comment: Thank you zapico for answering, let me try it!

Comment: In the simple project I made, I did it after InitializeComponents in the code-behind.        
        public MainPage() {
            InitializeComponent();
            Student stu = new Student();
            stu.Name = "Peter";
            stu.Age = 25;
            this.DataContext = stu;
        }

Comment: But, zapico, what troubles me is that when I run it from VS2012, it works perfectly fine, without doing any changes.

Comment: That's really strange... can't realize what's happening :-S Hope somebody knows and gives us some light!!